# VBA Change a 1 column array to a one dimensional array

Tags: arrays, vba

I am loading an array from a table.

```
aryNonE = ActiveSheet.Range("AA1:AA" & lRowNonE - 1)
test = Array("Bob Smith", "John Davies"...)
```

Want to use Filter but get type mismatch on aryNonE.
test works fine

[Debug shows[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTpFP.png)

How do I get aryNonE to look like test??

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way, please:

```
Sub test2DTo1DArray()
  Dim aryNonE, lRowNonE As Long
  
  lRowNonE = 10
  aryNonE = ActiveSheet.Range("AA1:AA" & lRowNonE - 1)              '2D array
  aryNonE = Application.Transpose(Application.Index(aryNonE, 0, 1)) '1D array
  'You can test it in this way:
  Debug.Print Join(aryNonE, ",")
End Sub
```

In this way, it can be used to filter using an array like `Criteria1`...

But, if the values in the 2D array are **numbers**, since the Criteria array must keep **only strings**, the range where the array is extracted from, must preliminarily be formatted as text.

Comment: We have a launch, She's cleared the tower!!  Thank you.

Comment: @DrD: Glad I could help!